# Tablesorter: change id after sort

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

In my table i have an [object HTMLInputElement] and i would like to change the id of this element. But this doesn't work:

`function BindFunctions() {

```
        $('table[id*="tbl_main"]').tablesorter();
        $('table[id*="tbl_main"]').bind("sortEnd",function() { 
            var table = document.getElementById('<%=tbl_main.ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                var e = row.cells[0].firstChild;
                e.id= '5';           
            }
        }); 
    };`
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: *"Can anyone help me ?"* Without seeing the related markup? Probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the related markup, it's *very* hard to help. But my guess is that the first child of the cell is a text node rather than an element. The DOM `firstChild` property gives you the first **node**, which may or may not be an element. For instance, if your table row looks like this:

```
<tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
```

...then `row.cells[0].firstChild` is a text node containing the text `"Foo"`.

Also note that your code, as quoted, will create an invalid DOM structure: You **cannot** use the same `id` on more than one element in the document. You're trying to give the `id` value `"5"` to the first child element of each row. `id` values **must** be unique.

Further, it looks like you're using jQuery (although you haven't tagged the question `jquery`). I'll just mention that while `"5"` is a valid `id` value for HTML, it is **not** a valid `id` value for CSS, and since jQuery uses CSS-style selectors, it's problematic to use invalid CSS `id` values with jQuery.

Comment: when i alert(e) i get an HTMLInputElement so i think it takes the right element. And when i debug i actually see that the id is set 5 but it doesn't commit this.

Comment: @user2235511: If it's actually an input element, then your code `e.id = "5";` will work. So that's not the problem you're having. Either it relates to the invalid structure you're trying to create, or whatever it is you're observing that makes you think it's not working is not down to the `id` at all.

Comment: Ok, your explanation helped. Thank you